# How to stop sign in / login every time I open a new document in sharepoint 2016 on premise

Tags: sharepoint-server

Once logged in to SharePoint 2016 on Premise, when we open a document, it asks to log in. If we have a word document opened and want to open another one, no log in required. But is we close the word document and try to open another one, we are asked to log in again.

Is there anything we can do to stop the log in when opening documents?

It gets very frustrating when we are opening many document every day.

This is in Windows 7. In Windows 10, it will ask for log in twice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable automatic logon with current username and password in IE.

To enable automatic logon with current user name and password, go to Internet Explorer->navigate to Settings -> Internet Options->On the Security tab, click Custom Level->Under User Authentication, select Automatic logon with current user name and password.
 [image]

Comment: Hi Amy, Thanks for your reply. I did do that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: you could add a new entry to Credentials Manager. You 
 could refer to the article.https://kb.intermedia.net/article/1668

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

- Your SharePoint URL should be in Internet Explorer Security Zone `Local Intranet`. It shouldn't be in `Trusted Sites` as many misunderstand (background: [The Intranet Zone](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/06/05/the-intranet-zone/))
- Make sure that the Local Intranet zone is configured to perform `Automatic logon with current user name and password` as @Amy_MSFT already mentioned.
- `Enable Protected Mode` for Local Intranet zone must be **disabled**. Background: [Persistent cookies are not shared between Internet Explorer and Office applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/932118/persistent-cookies-are-not-shared-between-internet-explorer-and-office)
  [image: Enable Protected Mode]

Comment: Hi Everyone. Sorry for the very late reply.

Still not working for us for some reason.

We're now working with IT department to see if there is a security issue in place.

Thanks everyone.